# Html long table print out , header padding after first page

Tags: css, html

I got a problem when I try to print a table which across several pages.
The table header will repeat every page, it's good, but the table header after first page will be too close to page header.

I do set page margin as zero, because I don't want to print the browser header/footer (e.g. url link, date..etc).
But it seems make the second page no margin before the table header.

Is there any way to leave some space before table header?

```css
@page {
  size: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 80px 30px 80px 30px;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```